# Evaluating xpath when value has multiple spaces

Tags: xpath

I want to evaluate xpath for a value that has multiple spaces in it.
eg- `"abc  def"` (2 spaces after abc)
When there is only 1 space after abc- `"abc def"`, xpath is getting evaluated as

```
//div[text()='"abc def"']
```

But on increasing the space, it's not able to locate the xpath.

Comment: What tool or language are you using to evaluate these XPath expressions?  If it's XSLT (or some other system where the XPath expressions are given in XML attributes) then remember that an XML parser will normalize all runs of whitespace within attribute values down to a single space before the expression is passed to the XPath parser.

Comment: I am using firebug to evaluate the xpath expression.

Comment: You may be able to test whether it's messing up the spaces by escaping them per JavaScript rules - `$x("//div[text() = 'abc\u0020\u0020def'")`.  The other question is whether the characters in the HTML you are trying to match are really spaces (U+0020) or whether they're other characters that look the same, such as no-break spaces (U+00A0).

Answer (score 0):

xpath [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function seems to be what you're looking for :

```
//div[normalize-space(text())='"abc def"']
```

Tested [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) with the following input :

```
<root>
    <div>"abc def"</div>
    <div>"abc   def"</div>
    <div>"abc       def"</div>
</root>
```

and the output is :

```
Element='<div>"abc def"</div>'
Element='<div>"abc   def"</div>'
Element='<div>"abc      def"</div>'
```

Comment: In my case the normalize-space is working for only 1 space. Normalize space is used to remove the trailing whitespaces. Here the spaces are kept intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xpath 2.0, you can use `matches()` :

```
//div[matches(text(),'abc\s*def')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In text, spaces are just like any other character. So searching for 
`text()="abc  def"` should work just fine.

In addition to include two spaces between `abc` and `def`,
do not quote the text with both single and double quotes:

```
//div[text()="abc  def"]
```